Where are thermostats located on dual element Theem electric water heaters?
We have a dual element Rheem electric water heater.  We can locate only 1 thermostat, where is the other?  The hot water is NOT HOT!

some dual element tanks still have only one thermostat.

What have you tested so far?

all dual element heaters have two thermostats one above the other at about 12 inches apart, under the individual covers

Please take the [tour]. Provide the model number of the heater and tell us if it's brand new and never worked, old and used to work, then stopped being hot, old and never worked, etc... Likewise, does "not hot" mean same temperature as the cold water, or just not as warm as you want, but warmer than the cold water?

The thermostats are on the elements themselves, which are typically fairly far into the side of the heater due to insulation (and potentially over-wrap insulation) and the service covers that have to be removed to access them. Be sure to shut off the breaker before going in there.
If it is new and has not made hot water ever, it might be plumbed backwards. If it used to make hot water and now does not, it might have a broken dip tube, a failed element, or two failed elements, or the circuit to it is tripped or has a bad connection.
